# creating complex network in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a complex network, the no. of nodes is controlled by slider. 
i want to create some nodes as target and some as sources. and want to connect them through edges.

```
breed [nodes node]
undirected-link-breed [edges edge]

to setup
;;
end
to add-nodes
create-nodes num-nodes [
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
end
```

how do I draw edges and to create some target and source nodes?

Comment: NetLogo ships with a Models Library that include an entire collection of network models.

Comment: You can also check out the NetLogo Complex Networks Toolbox, which I find quite helpful: http://www.cs.us.es/~fsancho/?e=162

Comment: In the NetLogo Dictionary, the relevant category of primitive is "Links".